# How to set values in numpy/tensorflow array from another array based on provided index list?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow2.0, array-broadcasting

Suppose, there are two arrays,

```
a = np.zeros(24)
b = np.ones(10)
```

and a index list,

```
c = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 11, 15, 17, 20, 22]
```

I can easily calculate the result with for loop,

```
for i, val in enumerate(c):
    a[val] = b[i]
```

res = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]

But, I am looking if there is any build-in method as I want to do it over a batch. Thanks for helping!

I can calculate it using for loop. But, I am looking for an build-in method if available as I need to do it over a batch.

Comment: if `len(c) == len(b)`, then `a[c] = b` should be enough

Comment: Thanks, do you know how can I do it over a 2-d array e.g. batch?

Comment: can you give me an example of what `a`, `b` and `c` would look like in your 2D use case ?

Comment: a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
b = np.array([[1, 4], [1, 2]])
c = [0, 2]
So, the output will be,
[[1, 0, 4, 0, 0], [1, 0, 2, 0, 0]]

Comment: Alright, then `a[:, c] = b` should work.